# I want to integrate a html template to react but scripts are not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, templates

[I know I placed them correct and when I do ctrl+click I can go to my scripts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAnd6.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and be precise about the issue you face. What errors do you receive? What output do you expect etc.? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem.